why won't sourcing a cshell command which redirects stdout & stderr to /dev/null in the background work
c-shell
I want to rm -rf a dir in the background and redirect stdout & stderr to /dev/null.  Like this...
rm -rf del_this_dir >& /dev/null &

This works fine when I type it in at the linux prompt.  It creates a new job and I never see the messages (went to /dev/null I believe).
But when I put this command in a file, then 'source' it, it...

does not send stdout/stderr to /dev/null
it runs but not in the background as a different job.

Understanding why it behaves like this would be great.  But getting a way to actually get it to do what I want would be greater :-)
#######  AUGMENTING WITH EXAMPLE ########
This is the script that illustrates the problem...
atletx7-reg027:/proj/verif_release/sqf/10.7.0.rc[ 106 ] --> cat test_rm.csh
set echo
set rmcmd="/usr/bin/env rm -rf /proj/can_sqf_er/IT_DELETE/kainiliu_240619_231639_canis_main  >& /dev/null &"
echo $rmcmd
date
$rmcmd
echo "done"
date

This is the results of running it...
atletx7-reg027:/proj/verif_release/sqf/10.7.0.rc[ 275 ] --> source test_rm.csh
set rmcmd=/usr/bin/env rm -rf /proj/can_sqf_er/IT_DELETE/kainiliu_240619_231639_canis_main  >& /dev/null &
echo /usr/bin/env rm -rf /proj/can_sqf_er/IT_DELETE/kainiliu_240619_231639_canis_main >& /dev/null &
/usr/bin/env rm -rf /proj/can_sqf_er/IT_DELETE/kainiliu_240619_231639_canis_main >& /dev/null &
date
Wed Jun 26 11:05:40 EDT 2024
/usr/bin/env rm -rf /proj/can_sqf_er/IT_DELETE/kainiliu_240619_231639_canis_main >& /dev/null &
rm: cannot remove '/proj/can_sqf_er/IT_DELETE/kainiliu_240619_231639_canis_main/import/iohub6_0_strix_iod1/src/rtl/iohub/common/misc/vericomLog/pes.bat': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/proj/can_sqf_er/IT_DELETE/kainiliu_240619_231639_canis_main/import/iohub6_0_strix_iod1/src/rtl/iohub/common/misc/vericomLog/turbo.log': Permission denied

 ... long list of messages I don't care to see, thus redirected to /dev/null...

rm: cannot remove '/proj/can_sqf_er/IT_DELETE/kainiliu_240619_231639_canis_main/out/linux_3.10.0_64.VCS/stx/tmp/dvdb/soc_apu.soc_jtag/last_cached.yaml.gz': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/dev/null': Permission denied
echo done
done
date
Wed Jun 26 12:20:54 EDT 2024

Notice the time elapsed (Wed Jun 26 11:05:40 - Jun 26 12:20:54) which proves this did not run in the background.
And the long list of 'permission denied' messages didn't go to /dev/null
#############  Another much simpler example  ##########
I want to run this script in the background.  A sleep followed by 'date'...
% cat 
bgproc.csh
#!/usr/bin/env tcsh
echo "in bgproc"
sleep 10
date
echo "leaving bgproc"

OK, run the script, send stderr/stdout to /dev/null, run in background
% bgproc.csh >& /dev/null &
[8] 4277
% jobs
[8]    Running                       bgproc.csh >& /dev/null
% jobs
[8]    Running                       bgproc.csh >& /dev/null
% jobs
[8]    Done                          bgproc.csh >& /dev/null
% jobs

OK, so that worked as expected.  In the background and I didn't see any of the output from bgproc.csh (presumably went to /dev/null)
Now lets put this command in a shell script that I will source.  I'll call that script "test_bgproc.csh"
% cat test_bgproc.csh
set echo
set bgpcmd="./bgproc.csh >& /dev/null &"
echo $bgpcmd
date
$bgpcmd
echo "done"
date

And now lets source test_bgproc.csh...
% source test_bgproc.csh
set bgpcmd=./bgproc.csh >& /dev/null &
echo ./bgproc.csh >& /dev/null &
./bgproc.csh >& /dev/null &
date
Wed Jun 26 18:42:42 EDT 2024
./bgproc.csh >& /dev/null &
in bgproc
Wed Jun 26 18:42:52 EDT 2024
leaving bgproc
echo done
done
date
Wed Jun 26 18:42:52 EDT 2024

You can see the 10 second delta in the times.  And you can see the output of bgproc.csh going to stdout... NOT /dev/null

There's no reason why that shouldn't work.  You are literally using the source command?  And if you cat the file, you see that the ampersands are present?

You might have CRLF line endings, which isn't good for UNIX scripts

It is highly unliekly that it behaves as you describe, without also producing an error message. Can you add a screenshot which shows this behaviour? And also put a set echo in your script file, so that we can see better what's going on.

In case you missed it, the C shell stopped being popular for very good reasons several decades ago (though perhaps not this particular one). https://hybras.dev/posts/2021-02-13-reasons-to-not-use-csh/

I augmented the initial post with an example that I just ran.
I work for a large corp and csh is what they use.  Yes, bash is better :-)

I added a second, simpler example that can be copied and tried

OK, finally figured it out.  Don't put the ">& /dev/null &" in the variable, rather, put that stuff in the line that runs the command.  So, using the 2nd example above, instead of...
set bgpcmd="./bgproc.csh >& /dev/null &" 
$bgpcmd

... do this instead....
set bgpcmd="./bgproc.csh"
$bgpcmd >& /dev/null &


don't even store a command in a string, use an array: set bgpcmd=(cmd with args) . though shell constructs can't be stored at all
